# SimpleXMLReader not working properly

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I've been trying to use [SimpleXMLReader](https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader)

to retrieve data from the following XML structure:

```
 <boutique>
       <produto num="228122907">
            <id_produto><![CDATA[70427038]]></id_produto>
            <nome><![CDATA[Solução Antirrugas - Kit]]></nome>
            <descricao><![CDATA[A melhor combinação do Pegolift com Vitamina C elevada ao extremo e as pluri funções do Pluri-Active. Experimente estes agentes.]]></descricao>
       </produto>
</boutique>
```

But I'm only being able to retrieve and echo the "num" node's value.
Like this result I get something like this:

```
/boutique/produto: 228122907 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823820 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823824 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823825 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823826 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823827 = 0;
```

It doesn't matter what I change, I can't seem to get the node `<nome>`value for example.
I'm using this software because I'm dealing with a pretty big XML file.

Download the XML here: `http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML`

Get SimpleXMLReader here: `https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader`

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: text/html, charset=utf-8;");
require_once dirname(__FILE__). "/simplexmlreader.php";
class ExampleXmlReader1 extends SimpleXMLReader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // by node name

        $this->registerCallback("nome", array($this, "callbackPrice"));
        // by xpath<br />
///////////////////// Nesta parte não mexe
        $this->registerCallback("/boutique/produto", array($this, "callbackRest"));
    }
    protected function callbackPrice($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $attributes = $xml->attributes();
        $ref = (string) $attributes->{"num"};
        if ($ref) {
            $price = floatval((string)$xml);
            $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
            echo "$xpath: $ref = $price;\n";
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected function callbackRest($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $attributes = $xml->attributes();
        $ref = (string) $attributes->{"num"};
        if ($ref) {
            $rest = floatval((string) $xml);
            $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
            echo "$xpath: $ref = $rest;\n";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/boutique.xml";
$reader = new ExampleXmlReader1;
$reader->open($file);
$reader->parse();
$reader->close();
```